# Testing lazy loaded routes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to write a test for navigation to a route in a lazy loaded module. It fails because the lazy loaded module can't be found. I don't know how to load/inject the lazy loaded module into the test.

This is main.ts:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: EagerComponent},
  {path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'app/lazy.module'}
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
 declarations: [ AppComponent, EagerComponent ],
 providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
 ],
 bootstrap: [ AppComponent ] 
}) 
class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Here is app/lazy.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: '', component: LazyComponent}
    ]) ],
  declarations: [ LazyComponent ],
  providers: [ LazyComponent ]
})
export default class LazyModule {
}
```

Here is the test spec. The '/' path works but the '/lazy' path gets:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module app/lazy.module



describe( 'Router', () => {
  beforeEach( () => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ RouterTestingModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes) ],
        declarations: [ AppComponent, EagerComponent, LazyComponent ]
      });
    }
  );

  beforeEach( async(() => {
      TestBed.compileComponents();
    }
  ));

  it('should be able to navigate to home using commands API',
    fakeAsync(inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {
        TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        router.navigate(['/']);
        tick();
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/');
      })
    ));

  it('should be able to navigate to /lazy using commands API',
    fakeAsync(inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {
        TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        router.navigate(['/lazy']);
        tick();
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/lazy');
      })
    ));
});
```

I'm running this on a Jasmine page using SystemJS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>[TEST] Lazy</title>

  <!-- TypeScript in-browser compiler -->
  <script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>

  <!-- Polyfills -->
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

  <!-- Jasmine -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- Zone.js -->
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>

  <!-- SystemJS -->
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs.test-config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  var SPEC_MODULES = [
    'app/app.routing.spec'//
  ];

  Promise.all([
        System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
        System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
      ])
      .then(function(modules) {
        var testing = modules[0];
        var browser = modules[1];

        testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
            browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

        // Load all the spec files.
        return Promise.all(SPEC_MODULES.map(function(module) {
          return System.import(module);
        }));
      })
      .then(window.onload)
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

systemjs.test-config.js

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true},
    map: {
      '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
      'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs',

      '@angular/common/testing'                  : 'ng:common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler/testing'                : 'ng:compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/core/testing'                    : 'ng:core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/http/testing'                    : 'ng:http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/testing'                  : 'ng:router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/testing'        : 'ng:platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'ng:platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js'
    },
    paths: {
      'node_modules/@angular/*': 'node_modules/@angular/*/bundles',
      'ng:': 'node_modules/@angular/'
    },
    meta: {
      '@angular/*': {'format': 'cjs'}
    },
    packages: {
      'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
      'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},

      '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'core.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/http'                    : {main: 'http.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'common.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'compiler.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/router'                  : {main: 'router.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'platform-browser.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js'}
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't test it. It's out of the realm of unit testing. Should be for e2e. Don't use he real routes for the test. That way it wont fail

Comment: Another thing is `fakeAsync` won't work, as an XHR request needs to be made for the module. XHR doesnt work with `fakeAsync`

Comment: Well I'm following the project structure used in _Angular 2 Development with TypeScript_ so I think I'll keep the route tests and xit the lazy loaded one for now.

Comment: I changed fakeAsync to async and used whenStable and the module does get loaded and the test proceeds. The test fails though as the location is '' instead of '/rhr' as I expected.